# AspNet Web Api Custom Path is Not Working with .json end in path route

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

i created a new project from visual studio 2019 of type web api
i want my endpoint like that /api/products.json but it not work

```
   <Route("/api/products.json")>
   <HttpGet()>
   Public Function RetriveData() As ListarRes

    Return New ListarRes()
   End
```

when i run the project swagger show perfect but if i test it return error 404

in configuration is enabled MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

the problem is due to ".json" if i chnaged for

```
   <Route("/api/products")>
```

it works, so how i should create it custom route?

Comment: What's the purpose of the .json?  Why not just use the formatting directives in the request headers?  are you planing on having something like api/products.json and api.products.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was very easy

asp.net web api - use style

extension == concrete handler

so i created mock handler and it worked

```
Public Class AppJsonExtension
  Implements IHttpHandler

  Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

  End Sub

End Class
```

and in the web.config added

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    ...
    <add name="JsonHandler" path="*.json" verb="*" type="TestApp.AppJsonExtension, TestApp" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```